# how to remove commas from search result in magento 2

Tags: magento2

[image]

i want to remove the search result commas see the image when magento returns sprite it in the commas and i want to remove this commas. how to achieve this am not sure if it possible with custom module or custom theme please guide me

Comment: You mean the single quotes around sprite?

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Block/Result.php - please check with this file.. line number - 195.

Comment: but how to remove that comma i have already found this file

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add after Plugin for this method `getSearchQueryText` in

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Block/Result.php

```
 public function getSearchQueryText()
    {
        return __("Search results for: '%1'", $this->catalogSearchData->getEscapedQueryText());
    }
```

to do this you need to add a plugin declaration in your module

> app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result">
        <plugin name="search_result_page_title_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Result" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and create `Result` Plugin class to remove commas

> app\code\Vendor\Module\Plugin\Result.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Result{
    protected $catalogSearchData;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data $catalogSearchData
    ) {
        $this->catalogSearchData = $catalogSearchData;
    }
    public function afterGetSearchQueryText(\Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result $subject, $phrase){
        return __("Search results for: %1", $this->catalogSearchData->getEscapedQueryText()); // any text here will replace the original title
    }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: can you explain that result.php more in deatil

Comment: Plugins is intended to override the core function of Magento, you can use before, after and around. so we used after plugin to override the output of the main function and return our desired phrase. you can read more about plugins here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: this is not working though

Comment: Sorry, i added the wrong class in `di.xml` file. please check the edited answer

Comment: do i  have to create block file also

Comment: getting error on line 5

Comment: well, my mistake again, catalogSearchData is protected and we need to inject it in our plugin, so we can read the query from it. Please check the updated answer, tested and working

Comment: also tell em do i need to create block also in my custom module

Comment: You don't need to create block in your custom module, this plugin will override the title. you will need to create a custom block if you need to add extra functionalities in this page.